# How to change eslint settings to understand absolute import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I use create-react-app and I want to use absolute import from `./src`.

As Dan Abramov [recommended](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2188) I added `.env` with `NODE_PATH=src` and it works.

But my eslint doesn't understand that module already exists. I get error `import/no-unresolved` and `import/extensions`

This is my eslint-config:

```
module.exports = {
parser: 'babel-eslint',
extends: 'airbnb',
rules: {
    'react/no-did-mount-set-state': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
    'no-use-before-define': 'off',
    'arrow-body-style': 'off',
    // uncommit on developing
    'no-console': 'off',
    'no-debugger': 'off',
  },
  globals: {
    browser: true,
    fetch: true,
    serviceworker: true,
    describe: true,
    it: true,
    expect: true,
    document: true,
  },
```

};

And of course it will good if vscode will make suggests for me by 'src'.

Comment: do you just want to hide the eslint warning, or you want it to detect if the path is correct?

Comment: of course I can just turn off these rules, but may be there is the chance to continue to look for files.

Comment: use `/* eslint-disable rulename */` at the beginning of the file you don't want to be eslint-ed.

Comment: your question is exactly my answer. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 72):

You need to use `eslint-plugin-import`: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import

And configure your eslint settings in `.eslintrc`

```
module.exports = {
  ...   
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Then, you can use import from `src` folder.

Example, if you have `src/components/MyComponent.jsx`, you will write this:

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent.jsx';
```

Comment: Still having the same issue,  after applying this.. any updates ?

Comment: This didn't work for me either, Rehan, but this did:

`"settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: I have issue with importing in files at root. How can that be resolved?

Comment: hi. so far i do this and every thing is just fine but when it comes to resolve @material/core it can not resolve it

Answer (score 21):

It's a bit late, but the above answers didn't solve the problem for me. After some research, I found [this article](https://dev.to/oliverandrich/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-and-vscode-ihn) that made it work for me.

**Install eslint-plugin-import**

`npm i -D eslint-plugin-import`

**jsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**eslintrc.json**

```json
{
  "extends": ["react-app", "plugin:import/errors", "plugin:import/warnings"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're extending airbnb's eslint config, which includes `eslint-plugin-import`, which has the following rule enabled by default: `no-absolute-path`.

See:
https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-absolute-path.md

You may need to tweak more rules beyond that.

Comment: I read the link but it's a bit confusing for me since I'm new to rust/wasm/js. If I have `import loadWasm from '/Users/tymac/web/src/lib.rs';` does that mean I need to define the path first in eslintrc.json? Could you please add to your answer using my path as an example if possible?

Comment: As a relative path quick fix I just copied the lib.rs file into the current directory which is one level above the import statement. Therefore `import loadWasm from '../lib.rs';`. But it would be nice to know how to conform to airbnb eslint.

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to get this to work with Vite import aliases, the following slight modification of @guillaume-jasmin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50235708/1852466) worked for me. Our project was using `@` as the alias for our `src` directory, which the import plugin didn't like since it wants an actual directory. To workaround this, I modified our `vite.config.js` to alias our `src` directory as `src`. This allows us to do imports like `import SomeComponent from "src/components/SomeComponent"`. Here are the configuration changes in code (we're using Vite for a Vue 2 app):

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
      'src': path.resolve(_dirname, '/src'),
    }
  }
})
```

And then the ESLint config:

```js
// eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: [path.resolve(__dirname)]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I left the `@` import alias in there so that we can gradually migrate over files as ESLint flags them (we only run ESLint on changed files).

Answer (score -2):

This is a quick fix, not the best solution.

Omar Baharets's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50235608/15741905) inspired me for this solution.

If you are using `airbnb` plugin with `eslint` and this error is caused by that plugin, you can simply disable the rule (`import/no-unresolved`) that gives the error like this:

```
//.eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
...,
rules :{
 ...,
 'import/no-unresolved': 'off',
 }
}
```